# Merge Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka

In `Kafka`, I have three topics, whose content is produced with `Kafka Connect`. Here is an example:

```
PersonTopic
  - person_id
  - person_name

AddressTopic
  - address_id
  - person_id
  - address_text

ChildrenTopic
  - child_id
  - person_id
  - child_name
```

Is there a way to collect messages that consist of data from all three topics?
I am also interested in dealing with corner cases, for example if records from child topics arrive late. I can use `Kafka-Connect`, `KSQL` or steam API, or whatever gets the job done.

Example of the desired result:

```
ResultTopic
  - person_id
  - person_name
  - addresses
    - address1 { address_id, address_text }
    - address2 { address_id, address_text }
  - children
    - child_1 { child_id, child_name }
    - child_2 { child_id, child_name }
    - child_3 { child_id, child_name }
```

Comment: Ksql joins should work. What issues are you running into?

Comment: I am working on a small data set, so I have no idea what happens if the child stream lags behind the parent. For example, child stream might get a 5 sec delay.

Comment: Another issue is that I have no idea whether KSQL can produce such result.

Comment: You'll need to account for time windows, yes. The Kafka Streams documentation covers this in good detail, but generally, events outside of an expected range are ignored. Kafka Connect itself doesn't join topics, but it could write to a database where you could write join queries there too, however, you'll still have eventual consistency problems with late events